How to publish results in Testrail with pytest and trcli?
Recently, as a beginner, I started a project to automate tmanual testing for a small web application, and after a lot of work, I reached the point where I'm stuck when I want to publish the test results in Testrail. I've searched a lot on the internet, but I found some code examples written only for specific contexts that I don't understand.
So I've installed the pytest, and trcli, but after the test is finished, the results are not published in the Testrail, and I don't know what I'm missing or what I need more of in order to publish the results in the Testrail as Pass/Fail.
The code I'm running (the script is run with a parameter, ex: testscript.py user8):
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from pytest_testrail.plugin import testrail, pytestrail
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from . import g_access
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
ServiceObj = Service('C:\Python\chrome_driver\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = ServiceObj, options = chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()


def login_func():

    if g_access.arg_c in g_access.user_dict:

        driver.get(g_access.SttHomePage); time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, g_access.username_field).send_keys(g_access.user_dict[g_access.arg_c][0]); time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, g_access.MNext).click(); time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, g_access.keep_signed_in).click; time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, g_access.ENext).click(); time.sleep(18)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, g_access.password_field).send_keys(g_access.user_dict[g_access.arg_c][1]); time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, g_access.EAVerify).click(); time.sleep(7)

        expected_elm = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, g_access.homepage_msg)

        try:
            assert expected_elm.text == "Wellcome!"; print("Assertion Passed")
        except AssertionError:
            print("Assertion Failed")
            pass

The issue is that I don't know what I need in order to successfully publish  the Pass or Fail results to testcases in the testrun.
